What is a Bazel analogue of `.PHONY` rules (as in GNU Make)?
I am a Bazel novice and don't have any practical experience yet.
What is a Bazel analogue of .PHONY rules (in GNU Make), that is targets that possibly don't create actual files in the filesystem and rebuilt whether the target exists or no?
That is, how to create and to pass to Bazel an intermediary rule that does not create a target file? For example, what may be Bazel code for install rules?

Create a binary and use bazel run. Put everything it needs from other Bazel rules (files to install, dependencies, etc) in its runfiles. Binaries are created using a rule with executable = True, either a builtin one like sh_binary or cc_binary or a custom one.

I am interested in more general case than copying files. For example I could install binaries into blockchain (not into file system) by running dfx deploy ... command. Please, explain what to do in this general case, too.

Sure, I reworded to clarify that. All dependencies you want Bazel to build before running the binary go in runfiles, whether those are files you want to install or anything else.
